# Align rectangles on date axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to draw a rectangle to indicate a range within the x axis. I can use locators for setting ticks and labels, but I don't seem to succeed using them to draw the rectangle. How could I go about it?!

```
import datetime as DT
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates

ddata = [DT.datetime.strptime('2010-02-05', "%Y-%m-%d"),
         DT.datetime.strptime('2010-02-19', "%Y-%m-%d"),
         DT.datetime.strptime('2010-03-05', "%Y-%m-%d"),
         DT.datetime.strptime('2010-03-19', "%Y-%m-%d"),]

values = [123,678,987,345]

d1 = zip(ddata,values)

def nplot(data):

    x = [date for (date, value) in data]
    y = [value for (date, value) in data]

#     Set the stage
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    graph = fig.add_subplot(111)

#     Plot the data as a red line with round markers
    graph.plot(x,y,'r-o')

    days   = dates.DayLocator(interval=7)  # every week
    months   = dates.MonthLocator()  # every month

#     Create locators and ticks
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(days)
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%d'))

    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('\n\n%b'))
    ax.xaxis.grid(True, which="major", linewidth=2)

#     Now how do I align a rectangle with specific dates?
    gca().add_patch(Rectangle((data[0][0], 1000), 
                    data[2][0], 1000, facecolor='w', alpha=0.9)) # doesn't work

    plt.show()

nplot(d1)
```

[image: Resulting image]

Comment: The code you have given provides a lot of detail but it isn't entirely clear (at least to me) what the question is. I suspect [the third demo here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html) will help you.

Comment: @Greg, it might, I'll try tomorrow. My example doesn't show it (because I don't know how to do it), but I want to fill between each second pair of date locators. Ultimately, I would like to fill between quarters (Jan to Mar, then Jul to Sep, etc), regardless of where the axis limits are. And to top it up, I would like the borders of the fill to be _between_ month ticks, so it is clear which months belong to the quarter. Not asking too much? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this I get the currently set minor ticks

```
locs = ax.xaxis.get_minorticklocs()
```

And with this I write the rectangle. Odd, the location of the left side is a 6-digit float, but the location for the right side is the number of days since the left side. No idea how that works, but it seems to...

```
gca().add_patch(Rectangle((locs[0], 0), 7, 1000, facecolor='w', alpha=0.9))
```

And this is what I wanted to do from the beginning: to mark recurring ranges.

```
locs = ax.xaxis.get_minorticklocs()
loc_len = len(locs)
zloc = zip(locs, [7] * loc_len) # Seven-day loops
for i in zloc[::2]:
    gca().add_patch(Rectangle((i[0], 0), i[1], 1000, facecolor='w', alpha=0.9))
```

[image: Final image]

**However**, this won't work if I decide to box months, as each month has a different number of days. @Greg's suggestion of using **fill_between** is another option, but it will set its limits in relation to the data, not the scale (which is OK, I guess):

```
xloc = zip(x[:-1], x[1:])
for i in xloc[::2]:
    ax.fill_between(i, 0, 1200, facecolor='w', alpha=0.5)
ylim(0, 1200)
plt.show()
```

[image: Final image]